# access contacts' email addresses on react-native

Tags: email, react-native, contacts

I need your help.
Do you know any way to access email address of phone contacts on the react-native?

I found there are some components like 'react-native contacts', 'react-native addressbook-ios'. But I do not know whether I can get contacts' email addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [rt2zz/react-native-contacts](https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts) you can retrieve all the information in the phone's contacts including email address.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Create React Native App` bootstrap, then you have the `Expo API` which includes a call for [Contacts](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/contacts.html#content)